# What is the difference between non-bracket and bracket in java?

Tags: java, if-statement, brackets

I wonder when idx is -1 why this causes the runtime exception.
It says the array cannot access cause idx is -1. But in my thought, idx -1 doesn't match the first condition (idx >= 0) so it should skip the next condition (open[idx] ,,,)

```
    if ((idx >= 0) && (open[idx] == '(') || (open[idx] == '{')) {
```

However, this code pass

```
    if ((idx >= 0) && ((open[idx] == '(') || (open[idx] == '{'))) {
```

I cannot understand why two conditional statements work differently. Please help me explain. Thanks

Comment: Parentheses work just like in math - they group operations to override operator precedence.

Comment: in the second case, the other checks are not being evaluated because of Short-Circuiting, this is why you don't get an exception. It's not purely the evaluation order, but you also need to understand how short circuiting works

Comment: I got it. It's like A && B || C  In this case, it fails because C. Thanks!